# Bcrypt password comparison doesn't work. Even user.password is empty in Node.js Express App

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, bcrypt

Here I'm learning MongoDB with Node.js Express App.
I'm securing my passwords with Bcrypt. Encryption and saving in mongodb is successful, but when I try to compare passwords for SigIn, it just fails.

> **SignUp route**

```
router.post('/signUp', (req, res, next) => {

let userData = req.body;

mongoose.connect(DB_URL, {useNewUrlParser: true}, (err) => {

    if (err) throw err;

    console.log('DB is connected Successfully');
    
    bcrypt.hash(userData.password, saltRounds, function (err, hash) {

        User.create({
            name: userData.name,
            fname:userData.fname,
            email:userData.email,
            password:hash
        }).then(() => {
            //success callback
            res.send('Saved');

        }).catch(next);
    });
 });
});
```

> **SignIn route**

```
router.post('/signIn', (req, res) => {

const incomingEmail = req.body.email;
const incomingPassword = req.body.password;

mongoose.connect(DB_URL, {useNewUrlParser: true}, (err) => {

    if (err) throw err;

    console.log('DB is connected Successfully');

    User.find({incomingEmail}).then((user) => {
        if (user.length > 0) {
            bcrypt.compare(incomingPassword, user.password).then(function (result) {

                res.status(200).json({status: 200, data: user[0]});

            }).catch(() => {

                res.send('incorrect password')

            });

        } else {
            res.status(404).json({status: 404, data: 'User not found'});
        }
    }).catch(() => {
        res.status(404).json({status: 404, data: 'Email not matched'});
    });
  });
});
```

With valid credentials for signin it shows

> `{"status": 404, "data": "User not found" }`

Even I try to send only password if email is matched, still it returns nothing.

```
User.find({incomingEmail}).then((user) => {
        res.send(user.password);
    }).catch(() => {
        res.status(404).json({status: 404, data: 'Email not matched'});
    });
```

I'm using WebStorm on Windows 10.

node version is **11.12.0**

Project package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"bcrypt": "3.0.4",
"body-parser": "latest",
"cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
"debug": "~2.6.9",
"express": "~4.16.0",
"mongodb": "^3.1.13",
"mongoose": "^5.4.17",
"mongoose-unique-validator": "^2.0.2",
"morgan": "~1.9.0"


}
```

If anyone have answer let me know. Thanks

Comment: Try `User.find({email: incomingEmail})` instead.

Comment: Agree with @LawrenceCherone, your schema doesn't seem to have `incomingEmail` field in it. Also there's no need to establish a connection with mongodb via `mongoose.connect` under each route. Just connect to the database once you bootstrap the application.

Comment: Point being "your code" actually says `User.find({ incomingEmail: incomingEmail })` that's how destructuring works

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yeah it worked but still  `res.send(user.password)` responding empty. here i just need to know how to pick specific item and send it as response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. I have tested it on my side here. The only anomaly I am looking at is while sending the response  you are having an Array of Responses but reading it as a single object.

Here is what the above jargon I said means

**INSTEAD OF**

```
User.find({incomingEmail}).then((user) => {
    res.send(user.password);
}).catch(() => {
    res.status(404).json({status: 404, data: 'Email not matched'});
});
```

**Do this**

```
User.find({incomingEmail}).then((user) => {
        res.send(user[0].password);
    }).catch(() => {
        res.status(404).json({status: 404, data: 'Email not matched'});
});
```

> OR IN ANOTHER CASE

what I can see you can do is to instead of using MONGOOSE ONLY FIND method ! you can go with **FINDONE** method too so that it would have no need to read out an array of JSON responses for a single user.  **FINDONE** will help you with the code you already have.